# One-to-many relationship without column that represent "one"

Tags: sql, sql-server, one-to-many

I have 2 tables: Group, Person and Address.

Group:

```
Id| Name| ...
```

Person:

```
Id| FirstName| LastName|...
```

Address:

```
Id| Address1|Address2|...
```

Table Address should contains multiple records from Group or from Person.
In general I would like to create relationship one(Group)-to-many(Address), but I don't want to add column `GroupId` into table `Address`.

How can I create this connection?

Would it be like many-to-many structure? When I need to create additional table GroupAddress, but just add constraint for unique id from `Group` table?

Comment: If you don't want to add the `groupId` to the `Address` table then yes, you can certainly just create a new table to hold the relationship between groups and addresses. But the constraint on that new table wouldn't be unique on group id, it would be unique on *address id*. All you're really doing here is saying "my address table has an extra column, but instead of being on the address table, it's on that table over there". So the primary key of "that table over there" must be the same as the primary key for the address table.

Comment: @allmhuran, but can I do not add any constraint here at all? All the job will be handled by backend... or better to have some constaints on table?

Comment: You should create the new table as: `create table GroupAddress (AddressId <datatype> primary key foreign key references Address(id), GroupId <datatype> foreign key references Group(id))`. If you don't put a unique constraint/primary key on the address id column then you are not enforcing your desired cardinality, and it would be possible to enter data such that there were many groups to an address, which is not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

As [allmhuran](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7165279/allmhuran) suggested in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72908537/one-to-many-relationship-without-column-that-represent-one#comment128775522_72908537). You **can** create a new table with a `foreign key` to both tables, but you *should* add a `unique constraint` on the address, so it should enforce a one-to-many relationship, and not allow many-to-many.

There are two ways you can do it, one:

```sql
create table [schema].GroupAddress
(
    GroupAddressId int not null identity primary key,
    GroupId <datatype> <foreign_key_constraint_name> foreign key references Group(id),
    AddressId <datatype> <foreign_key_constraint_name> foreign key references Address(id) <unique_constraint_name> unique
)
```

Or you can make the `AddressId` column as the `primary key`, and that will become a `unique` column, but you shouldn't make it as `identity` because that will create issues inserting on the `identity column`.

I would rather go with the first one (creating three columns), because it's generally a good thing to have a separate id column on each table.

The reason I say you ***can** create a new table*, is because the best way to do it, is by creating a new column on the address table.

Comment: There's no need for a `GroupAddressId` surrogate key. The `AddressId` is already the candidate key and should be declared as the primary key.

Comment: @allmhuran That's what I say *Or you can make the AddressId column as the primary key*, but I think it's generally a good thing to have a separate id column on each table. You can never know when you'll need it, and it doesn't add to the size of the database.

Comment: Well, of course it *does* add to the size of the database, but that's not really the issue. The issue is that it doesn't achieve anything. Blindly adding surrogates all over the place is something of a disease in the industry. I blame Eric Evans.